# Helm templating seems to only render alphabetically

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Im trying to template volumes and volumemounts in a deployment.

**The output i want is:**

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: appsettings
    mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/appsettings.json
    subPath: appsettings.json
volumes:
  - name: appsettings
    configMap:
      name: appsettings-file
```

**Here is my values.yml:**

```
volumemounts:
  - name: appsettings
    mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/appsettings.json
    subPath: appsettings.json
volumes:
  - name: appsettings
    configMap:
      name: appsettings-file
```

**Here is my template:**

```
{{- with .Values.volumemounts }}
volumeMounts:
{{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
{{- end }}
{{- with .Values.volumes }}
volumes:
{{- print . | nindent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```

**Here is the output:**

```
volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/appsettings.json
      name: appsettings
      subPath: appsettings.json
volumes:
    - configMap:
        name: appsettings-file
      name: appsettings
```

---

If i change line 2 and 6 in values.yml to be `- aname: appsettings`
The output is:

```
volumeMounts:
    - aname: appsettings
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/appsettings.json
      subPath: appsettings.json
volumes:
    - aname: appsettings
      configMap:
        name: appsettings-file
```

So it seems helm always gets the array in alphabetical order.
(i also tried with `print` instead of `toYaml`, ofcourse it gave an error but i saw that it still fetched they array sorted alphabeticaly:`[map[configMap:map[name:appsettings-file] name:appsettings]]`)

What am i missing ? How should i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toYaml` in fact alphabetizes dictionary keys.  This doesn't usually matter; Kubernetes will treat both versions of the pod spec the same.  If you want the dictionary to be serialized in a specific order, you'll need to write out the keys by hand.

In this particular case, I probably wouldn't try to make this low-level detail of the pod spec be configurable.  I'd write it out in the template file instead.  If this entire ConfigMap mount is optional, put it behind a single shared `{{ if .Values.mountConfig }}` option.  That would also remove the `toYaml` call.

Comment: In my chart i have multiple deployments which have none or many volumes and mounts. What i wanted to achieve is that i configure all of that in values. I only tried to template it and saw that the output was not as i intended but never tried to deploy it. It is as you say "This doesn't usually matter; Kubernetes will treat both versions of the pod spec the same." I tried to deploy and it works just fine :)

Comment: I think that although the output might be surprising to read by a human being, this behavior is actually correct. Without the sorting, subsequent renders of the same chart and values might yield different outputs. The sorting guarantees the idempotence of that data structure’s rendering output.